Request body is too large in supabase
Im trying to restore a single table from supabase backup. I downloaded the backup file, extracted it and I found a COPY (col1, col2, .., coln) FROM stdin; command followed by all the records. There are 3.1K records to import.  When I try to paste that into the Supabase query in web UI and execute that, I get Error: {"error":"Request body is too large"}. How Can I get this command executed?

Directly connect to the database instead of using the web UI?

I ended up using PSQL cli to run this copy from a script file.
